# How to create joints in Sprite Kit (Xcode)?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit

I don't understand how to create a joint to connect two bodies in SpriteKit.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The principle is the same for all joint types. First, create a joint connecting two bodies with some additional parameters (refer to the [Sprite Kit Framework reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SpriteKitFramework_Ref/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013041) for details). Then add the newly created joint to the physics world:

```
CGPoint anchor = CGPointMake(100, 100);
SKPhysicsJointFixed* fixedJoint = [SKPhysicsJointFixed jointWithBodyA:aBody 
                                                                bodyB:otherBody
                                                               anchor:anchor];
[self.scene.physicsWorld addJoint:fixedJoint];
```

Now smoke it!

Comment: Do you know if i can add a texture to the joint?

Comment: Not directly. If you know where the joint anchor is you can place a sprite there.

Comment: The problem is how can I get the positions of the anchor points when the joint is moving... By the way I'm using a limit joint.

Comment: you can only estimate it by calculating the middle point between the two bodies