# Sticking Node to another Node when Colliding

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit, collision-detection, collision

I am making an iOS game(swift xcode).

there is a car that moves constantly(SKAction) and a player which you can move with swipe gestures.

All good, but now I want that if the player touches the car, it will move the same with the car(it gets sticked to the car)

Now how do I do this?

I tried many things but none of them worked Smoothly..

I tried to use

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(car.frame, player.frame)) {
car.position = player.position
}
```

this works, but the player gets kicked to the middle of the car, I do not want this.
What I want is that if the player touches the bottom of the car, it gets sticked to the bottom of the car.

How do I do that??

for the collision detecion I also tried to use:

```
 func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact!) {
    var firstBody:SKPhysicsBody
    var secondBody:SKPhysicsBody

    if(contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask){
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB
    }else{
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }


    if((firstBody.categoryBitMask & CarCategory) != 0 && (secondBody.categoryBitMask & playerCategory) != 0)
    {


    }

}
```

But I Do not know what to put between the brackets to make it function smoothly like I want.

Comment: Why aren't you using the built in collision detection from sprite kit?

Comment: Do you mean the didbegincontact? (See edit)

Comment: Yes. See my answer with more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can connect the two nodes with a fixed physics joint. Physics joints, in general, connect two physics bodies that are in the scene. The fixed version, `SKPhysicsJointFixed`, joins two bodies such that they act as a single body.

Here's an example of how connects two physics bodies with a fixed joint:

First, add this to your `SKScene` subclass (e.g., GameScene.m)

```
func joinPhysicsBodies(bodyA:SKPhysicsBody, bodyB:SKPhysicsBody, point:CGPoint) {
    let joint = SKPhysicsJointFixed.jointWithBodyA(bodyA, bodyB: bodyB, anchor: point)
    self.physicsWorld.addJoint(joint)
}
```

and add this in the `if` statement in `didBeginContact`

```
self.joinPhysicsBodies(firstBody, bodyB:secondBody, point:contact.contactPoint)
```

where `contact.contactPoint` is the point of the contact.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler way to do this without physics is to use [constraints](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKConstraint_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014320):

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(car.frame, player.frame)) {
    player.constraints=[SKConstraint.distance(SKRange(upperLimit: 100), toNode: car)]
}
```

This will ensure the player is at most 100 points away from the car (you can change this number to make it more realistic)

And when you want to detach the player:

```
player.constraints=[]
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement the SKPhysicsContactDelegate protocol:

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate
```

Set the delegate at the end of didMoveToView

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
  ...

  self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
}
```

Create global variables to store the collision categories:

```
let collisionCar: UInt32  = 0x1 << 0
let collisionPlayer: UInt32    = 0x1 << 1
```

Create a physics body for car and player:

```
car.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: car.size)
car.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
car.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
car.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = collisionCar
car.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = collisionPlayer
car.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0x0;

player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: player.size)
player.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
player.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
player.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = collisionPlayer
player.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = collisionCar
player.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0x0;
```

Implement didBeginContact:

```
    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
...
    }
```

Comment: yes thank you, I already have that, but I dont know what to put in function at didbegincontact to let it stick like I want. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Ok. Sorry I haven't read that. In that case you can use SKConstraints to implement a following behavior. I've written a small tutorial in my blog. Maybe that helps: http://stefansdevplayground.blogspot.de/2014/09/howto-implement-targeting-or-follow.html

Comment: Is there any easier way? I tried your way, but it Does not work like I want, And how can i prevent the follower from rotating when following?

Comment: Perhaps. But I have no other idea at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this.

You can use joints, as detailed here [How to create joints in Sprite Kit (Xcode)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18931353/how-to-create-joints-in-sprite-kit-xcode)

Or you can just remove the player node from the world and add it as a child of the vehicle node, in which case the vehicle node and player node will be linked and will move together. Do this with `removeChildWithName()` and `addChild()`.

Comment: car.addChild(player) like this? When I do this it moves the same but the positions are different and I dont know why, I tried to change with player.position = CGPointMake() but for some reason that doesnt work??

Comment: What do you mean by "positions are different"? I assume you want the player to be "hit" by the car and sort of sit on the bonnet as the car moves along, correct? Adding the player as a child will keep the player in the same position where it was hit by the car.

Comment: and when you set the position of the player, it sets it relative to the parent. So you need to keep in mind it is no longer being positioned relative to the world, but to the car instead.

Comment: yes but the car is added at x.position = 50, and when i add the player as child of car the player is added at position.x = 50 from the car..

Comment: Exactly what I just said, the player will be placed relative to the car.

Comment: how can i change the position of the player? player.position = cgpointmake doesnt work..